# How to call doPost() from my action bean?

Tags: java, servlets, stripes

I have an actionbean receiving a form POST request:

```
public class MyBean implements ActionBean {}
```

I need to handle the POST data, looks like I need to override doPost() or doGet() but that can only be done if I extend HttpServlet? Which I can't because implementing ActionBean? I've just tried creating another class which extends HttpServlet to handle it but the overrides don't get called?

Thanks!

Comment: You can extend and implement at the same time... none the less, I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about it. So what exactly do you mean by "handle the Post data"? What do you want to do to it?

Comment: Yeh I'm picking up where someone has left off. I basically just need to receive some form input an assumed getting it /w an actionbean was the way to do it. Should I not use an actionbean and just have a servlet class? We've been receiving GET variables with the beans fine, was thinking could do the same

Comment: I don't recall having to override methods to get the value of a post...but it seems I don't have my code atm...so I'm afraid I can't help just yet

Comment: Hey Perry, I've just figured it out, thanks for your help! Have managed to get it within the actionbean, by going getContext().getRequest().getParamter("myParam"); :)

Comment: You're not using [Servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). You're using [Stripes](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stripes/info). Concentrate on [Stripes documentation](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post data parameters are directly mapped to setters in a Stripes ActionBean (don't use getContext().getRequest().getParameter..!) Please see [Stripes helloworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripes_%28framework%29) example.